# Permutation series

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutation-cycles

I need your help about a series :
$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^* \backslash\left\{ 1 \right\} \mbox{, } \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \sigma(1) $$
My goal is to give an explicit formula for this series. I tried to understand this with $n = 2$ and $n = 3$. For $n = 2$ we have identity and transposition in $S_2$ so

$$ \sum_{\sigma \in S_2} \sigma(1) = \mathrm{id}(1) + \tau(1) = 1 + 2 = 3 $$

For $n = 3$, we have identity, 3 transposition and 2 $3$-cycle in $S_3$ so

$$ \sum_{\sigma \in S_3} \sigma(1) = \mathrm{id}(1) + \tau_1(1) + \tau_2(1) + \tau_3(1) + c_1(1) + c_2(1) = 1 + (1+2+3) + (2+3) = 2(1+2+3)=12 $$

I thought this series links to $\sum_{k = 1}^n k$ because it works for $n = 2$ but fails for $n = 3$... I'm here to ask you an indication, please. Thank you.

Comment: It will be $$(n-1)!\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}2=\frac{(n+1)!}2.$$

Comment: Basically, each value $1,2,\dots,n$ occurs the same number of times in your sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $i = 1, ..., n$, let $T_i = \lbrace \sigma \in S_n \mid \sigma(1)=i \rbrace$.

One has
$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \sigma(1) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{\sigma \in T_i} \sigma(1) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{\sigma \in T_i}  i = \sum_{i=1}^n   i \times \mathrm{Card}(T_i)$$

Moreover,  for every $i=1, ..., n$, one has $\mathrm{Card}(T_i)=(n-1)!$. Indeed, the following map is bijective :
$$\varphi : \left|\begin{array}{ccc} T_i &\rightarrow & S_{n-1} \\ \sigma & \mapsto &\tau\end{array}\right.$$

where $\tau$ is defined by $\tau(k) =   \left\lbrace\begin{array}{cl} 1  & \text{ if } k=\sigma^{-1}(1)-1 \\ \sigma(k+1)-1 &  \text{ otherwise}\end{array}\right.$

So one deduces that $$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \sigma(1)  = (n-1)! \sum_{i=1}^n   i = (n-1)! \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

i.e. $$\boxed{\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \sigma(1)  = \dfrac{(n+1)!}{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew $\sum_{i = 1}^n i$ is here for something. For $\mathrm{card}(T_i) = (n-1)!$ How can you justify that equality? Is there a bijection to find or an induction proof is enough?

Comment: I edited the proof !

Comment: Its perfect. Thank you !